# How to get rowID on INSERT IGNORE

Tags: python, mysql

What would be the best way to get the PK of the following:

```
self.cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO table (url, country) VALUES (%s, %s)', (line['url'], line['country']))
```

In other words, if it's already there, I would need to get that PK, but if it's not there, it would be INSERTing and then getting the `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Is there a way to do this without doing three queries? What would be the best way to do this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `LAST_INSERT_ID` while inserting data, don't use `INSERT IGNORE`. Instead, use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to get the id:

```
INSERT INTO table (url, country)
VALUES (%s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
    id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

where `id` represents the unique column of your table.

You'd still need another query to fetch the updated `LAST_INSERT_ID` now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way to do this without altering previous data would be to do an `INSERT IGNORE` followed by a `SELECT` to retrieve the `id`.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO...')
cursor,execute('SELECT id FROM table...')
id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```